# Graph REST AddMember to Group - Bad Request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to add members to a group.  I am able to list all groups in my org, get user by email, get all users and **I can even remove a Member from a group** but I cannot add one - The error returned is `400 Bad Request`.

Here is the function which is the same function signature as those that work:  (I do have the `accesstoken`, valid group id and a valid member id)

I have confirmed the body data looks correct at least as far as I can see from the [example in the docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_members).

**Not sure what else I can add to make things clearer, ask and I'll update**

```cs
public async Task<string> AddGroupMember(string accessToken, string groupId, string memberId)
{
    var status = string.Empty;
    string endpoint = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members/$ref";
    string queryParameter = "";

    // pass body data 
    var keyOdataId = "@odata.id";
    var valueODataId = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{memberId}";

    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOdataId, valueODataId)
        };
    var body = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    try
    {
        using(var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint + queryParameter))
            {
                request.Content = body;
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                using(var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
                        status = "Member added to Group";
                    else
                        status = $"Unable to add Member to Group: {response.StatusCode}";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        status = $"Error adding Member to Group: {ex.Message}";
    }

    return status;
}
```

**Thanks for any help that anyone can offer - this is the last call I have to make then home free**

Comment: Found the issue for any who care to know for the future:


var body = new FormUrl... code is incorrect, what's needed is a simple json string


changed to this:


var body = new StringContent("{ \"" + keyOdataId + "\":\"" + valueODataId + "\" }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

kind of clunky but works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue for any who care to know for the future:

`var body = new FormUrl...` my code was incorrect, what's needed is a simple json string changed to this **UPDATED**:

`var jsonData = $@"{{ ""{keyOdataId}"": ""{valueODataId}"" }}";
var body = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

I would normally put the values in a class but this is for proof of concept and the json key needs to look exactly like this `@odata.id`

Answer (score 2):

Clarifying what is happening here:

The request body for this call should be JSON encoded (`application/json`). The [FormUrlEncodedContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) method returns your dictionary as Form encoded (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

You can write the JSON by hand (like you have so far) but a better solution would be to leverage [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). This will let you [encode the dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm) in much the same way you were with `FormUrlEncodedContent`:

```cs
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
       { keyOdataId, valueODataId}
    };
var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of work with Microsoft Graph, I would highly recommend switching to the [Microsoft Graph .NET SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).

You're method here would be far simpler using the SDK:

```cs
public async Task<string> AddGroupMember(string groupId, string memberId)
{
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = AuthenticationHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();
    User userToAdd = new User { Id = memberId };
    await graphClient.Groups[groupId].Members.References.Request().AddAsync(userToAdd);
}
```

Comment: I'll do the json.net conversion - I am doing a proof of concept for a future app to see how everything works.

The SDK does look easier, thanks for the tip and thanks for responding, gives me something to look at when we do the real deal.

Comment: simply converting the 'values' var as you described is not a winner:

`[{"Key":"@odata.id","Value":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/ee32df9c-6acc-453c-abb2-afb4380e364d"}]`

Should look like this:

`{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
}`

2nd, you can't serialize a collection into the 'body' as the body requires a type of StringContent and not just a string

Comment: Sorry, copy and pasted the wrong line. You should be using a Dictionary<string,string> instead of a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>).

Comment: Not a problem, the verbatim, interpolated string works well enough, six of one, half dozen of the other. Accepting your answer as the answer since it solves the issue and adds the good suggestion to use the SDK.