# Executing POST request for Microsoft Graph API to add members to an AD group

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

I am trying to add members to an AD groups invoking Microsoft Graph API through an Azure Function

It is very easy and straightforward to execute GET requests through Graph API's, but I can't find any examples how I could execute post requests for the Graph API

I do have an example of a post request for the Graph API which is

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 30

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
}
```

Here is the code I successfully use to retrieve the Graph response

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDirectoryUsers(string graphToken, TraceWriter log, string displayName)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", graphToken);

            string requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$top=2&$filter=displayName eq '" + displayName + "'&$expand=Members";
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), requestUrl);
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            return response;
        }
```

However, I am completely lost how I could execute the request through a C# code within the Azure function to ADD the retrieved users to another AD. How can construct the request URL? How should I handle the odata id within that request URL?

If anyone could help me in any way, I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: I found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573102/graph-rest-addmember-to-group-bad-request

Comment: I found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573102/graph-rest-addmember-to-group-bad-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer that worked for me

```
public static async Task<string> AddGroupMember(string accessToken, string groupId, string memberId)
{
    var status = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        string endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/" + groupId + "/members/$ref";
        string queryParameter = "";

        // pass body data 
        var keyOdataId = "@odata.id";
        var valueODataId = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/" + memberId;

        var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyOdataId, valueODataId)
};
        var jsonData = $@"{{ ""{keyOdataId}"": ""{valueODataId}"" }}";
        var body = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint + queryParameter))
            {
                request.Content = body;
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
                        status = "Member added to Group";
                    else
                        status = $"Unable to add Member to Group: {response.StatusCode}";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        status = $"Error adding Member to Group: {ex.Message}";
    }

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A reuse method for add sub-group/member to group(O365 doesn't support add sub-group to group now)

```
/// <param name="graphClient"></param>
  /// <param name="groupId"></param>
  /// <param name="memberId">memberId/sub-group id</param>
  /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task AddGroupMember1(GraphServiceClient 
    graphClient, string groupId, string memberId)
    { 
         User memberToAdd = new User { Id = memberId };
        //Group memberToAdd= new Group { Id = memberId };
        await graphClient.Groups[groupId].Members.References.Request().AddAsync(memberToAdd); 
   }
```

Comment: Any idea what to use for Microsoft.Graph 5.0? Trying to upgrade from the above but haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using graph api for sending email. The code in below

```
public async Task<dynamic> SendMail(string accessToken, MailWrapper mail)
        {
            try
            {
                GraphServiceClient graphClient = SDKHelper.GetMicrosoftAuthenticatedClient(accessToken);
                Message message = await BuildEmailMessage(graphClient, mail);
                await graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, true).Request().PostAsync(CancellationToken.None);
                var response = await graphClient.Me.MailFolders.SentItems.Messages.Request()
                                        .OrderBy(sendDateTimeDesc)
                                        .Top(1)
                                        .GetAsync();
                return await Task.FromResult(response);
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Assembly Microsoft.Graph, Version=1.9.0.0

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. However, I am still not sure how I could construct URL for the graph API with the odata portion I noted above

I modified my question a little but with a code example

Comment: There have an example

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_sendmail

Comment: Also have
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_post_messages

Answer (score 0):

That's what worked for me

```
public void AddUserToGroup(string groupId)
    {
        var requestUri = $"{_graphApiUrl}/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members/$ref";
        var id = "user_id";

        var OdataId = "@odata.id";
        var ODataValue = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}";

        var content = $@"{{ ""{OdataId}"": ""{ODataValue}"" }}";

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        using (var httpRequest = CreateHttpRequest(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri, content))
        {
            var response = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var reason = $"Status code: {(int)response.StatusCode}, Reason: {response.StatusCode}";
                throw new Exception(reason);
            }
        }
    }
```

And important thing was when creating a request to use:

```
request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

it didn't work with:

```
request.Content = new StringContent(content);
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=verbose");
```